# does default-lazy-init="true" works with component-scan

Tags: java, xml, spring

Here I have XML configuration:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bb.package1"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bb.package2"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bb.package3"/>

    <bean id="bean1" class="com.dot.basepackages.Bean1"/>
    <bean id="bean2" class="com.dot.basepackages.Bean2"/>
    <bean id="bean3" class="com.dot.basepackages.Bean3"/>
```

Does `default-lazy-init="true"` work only for beans created in this XML(Bean1, Bean2, Bean3) or also for beans found by spring with component-scan ?

Comment: It should work, see this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-3823

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, all the packages are still scanned at startup time.

Answer (score 0):

its same as @Lazy on Bean - if you want to scan Lazy you should say to spring what beans you want to be lazy